# (Swift) Is there a way to read user's input on the same line as the question?

Tags: swift, input, readline

**My code currently looks like this:**

Enter your number:

25

**I would like my code to look like this:**

Enter your number: 25

In other words, I would like to read an input from the user on the same line as the prompt. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes by changing the terminator of the `print` call

```
print("Enter your number: ", terminator: "")
```